# Can Space Engineers dedicate servers be saved manually?

Tags: space-engineers

So I built a dedicated server (as a windows service) for my brother and I to play on asyncronously, and set the auto-save interval to 24 hours. Today my brother and I spent several hours in game, and then I shutdown the dedicated server (stopped it through services.msc) to apply windows updates. Unfortunately, I assumed when shutdown it would auto-save my game. It did not.

Is there an option to do this? Alternatively, is there an option to save when a play enters/leaves the game? Anything other than the autosave interval?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing there is no option to save a dedicated server manually.
I highly suggest you lower the save rate to something of like 10 minutes.

With Dedicated Servers being unstable too at the moment, I also suggest to pull backups from your auto saves with [Shadow Copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy), which is included in Windows.

Comment: Aww poo, but I guess it is early access. I'll give that a go. Thanks for letting me know about the fact that it was unstable enough to require shadow copying.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command which saves the world and stops the server:

```
taskkill /IM SpaceEngineersDedicated.exe
```

I don't know though if this also works if you run it as a service.

See http://www.spaceengineersgame.com/dedicated-servers.html for more information.